# Roslyn analyser: Nullable annotations in Linq

Tags: linq, generics, roslyn, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

I am brand new to Roslyn and I have to write an analyser that will aid in improving nullable annotations when using Linq. The goal is to force any usages of .XYZOrDefault() to be stored in a nullable type variable/property/method signature. For example: if we use "var x = SomeKindOfList.FirstOrDefault()", "x" needs to be marked as nullable. We will be using C# 8, so I'm referring to NRTs. The idea of achieving this is by:

1. Determining if generic types are being used in the variable or
   method declaration
2. Use semantic model to determine if the left hand
       side of the expression's type is a nullable type
3. If left hand side of expression is not a nullable type, produce a
   diagnostic

I've gotten this far with my coding:

```
private static void AnalyzeNode(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
    {
        Compilation compilation = context.Compilation;
        var localDeclarations = context.Node.DescendantNodes().OfType<VariableDeclarationSyntax>(); 
        foreach (var declaration in localDeclarations)
        {
            // Find implicitly typed variable declarations.
            if (declaration.Type.IsVar)
            {
                foreach (var variable in declaration.Variables)
                {
                    var variableSymbol = ((ILocalSymbol)context.SemanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(variable)).Type;
                    var invocationSymbol = context.SemanticModel.GetOperation(variable.Initializer.Value).Type;

                    if (!((INamedTypeSymbol)variableSymbol).IsGenericType || declaration.Type.IsVar)
                    {
                        // For all such symbols, produce a diagnostic.
                        var diagnostic = Diagnostic.Create(Rule, variableSymbol.Locations[0], variableSymbol.Name);

                        context.ReportDiagnostic(diagnostic);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I've read so much about what you can do that at this stage it's an information overload. Any articles, code snippets or advise that can just give me some more direction would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Confused on the purpose.  `FirstOrDefault()` returns non-null for value types like `bool` or `int`.  Unless I'm mistaken, it only returns null for reference types.  Are you referring to nullable reference types?

Comment: Assuming you're talking about NRT's (it isn't clear): Note that this will work in .NET 5 -- `FirstOrDefault` will be properly annotated. You can use [ReferenceAssemblyAnnotator](https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/ReferenceAssemblyAnnotator) until then to get the newest annotations for the BCL

Comment: Perhaps you could add some code which your analyzer will pick up on? It's unclear whether you're referring to NRT's (you did tag it as C# 8), or `Nullable<T>`

Comment: My apologies, yes I'm referring to NRT's. I'll update the question to make this clear.

Comment: Your code is conditional on `System.Nullable`1`, which has nothing to do with NRT's. This is what confused me.

Comment: This is my first go at attempting this, so I do apologize if my intent in the code snippet is not clear. I'm just lost as to where a good starting point would be

Comment: I do think that the right thing to do is recognise that this functionality is already built into the compiler (provided that the call to `FirstOrDefault` is annotated correctly: if you're using something prior to .NET 5, use the ReferenceAssemblyAnnotator I mentioned earlier

Comment: Is there another analyzer that you can recommend I try out? I've been looking around on GitHub looking for alternatives while I wait for feedback regarding the ReferenceAssemblyAnnotator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end we ended up writing our own analyzer as an interim solution until we can move to .Net 5. The most basic implementation that we came up with was the following code:

```
    private static void AnalyzeNode(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
    {
        var localDeclarations = context.Node.DescendantNodes().OfType<VariableDeclarationSyntax>();

        foreach (var declaration in localDeclarations)
        {                
            foreach (var variable in declaration.Variables)
            {
                ITypeSymbol? variableSymbol = ((ILocalSymbol)context.SemanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(variable)).Type; 
                IOperation? invocationOperationInfo = context.SemanticModel.GetOperation(variable.Initializer.Value);

                if (invocationOperationInfo is IInvocationOperation op)
                {
                    if (op.TargetMethod.IsGenericMethod)
                    {
                        if (!((INamedTypeSymbol)variableSymbol).IsGenericType || declaration.Type.IsVar)
                        {
                            // For all such symbols, produce a diagnostic.
                            var diagnostic = Diagnostic.Create(Rule, variable.GetLocation());

                            context.ReportDiagnostic(diagnostic);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope this can help someone else who is, perhaps, just looking for a good starting point when having to develop something similar.